# File Encoding for NHTSA/OHI data

Tags: data-request

I am trying to do some analysis on data sources from this [site](https://www-odi.nhtsa.dot.gov/downloads/).

When I try to load it with pandas, I get a few different variants on the unknown byte error, depending on which encoding I use.

For example:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 729: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-ad328034813f> in <module>()
----> 1 flat_cmpl = pd.read_csv('FLAT_CMPL.txt', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    708 
--> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    710 
    711     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    453 
    454     try:
--> 455         data = parser.read(nrows)
    456     finally:
    457         parser.close()

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1067                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
   1068 
-> 1069         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1070 
   1071         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1837     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1838         try:
-> 1839             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1840         except StopIteration:
   1841             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 729: invalid start byte
```

I've tried a few different options including utf-8, utf-16, and ascii and a few others with no luck.

Do any of you know what the right encoding is for these files or how to find it?

Comment: I believe that the encoding is `latin1`.  I was at least able to load it as such but it's a bit frustrating that it's not documented on the site.